# Bats don't drop items they are holding in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to make bats drop items when you kill them by equipping them in their armor or weapon slot, but when I killed them they didn't drop the item. I tried using `/give` and `/replaceitem` but it didn't work. Here are the commands I tried:

```
/replaceitem entity @e[type=bat] slot.weapon.mainhand
minecraft:feather 1 0 {HideFlags:5,Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Bat
Fang"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}

/replaceitem entity @e[type=bat] slot.armor.head minecraft:feather 1 0
{HideFlags:5,Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Bat
Fang"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}

/give @e[type=bat] minecraft:feather 1 0 {HideFlags:5,Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"BatFang"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}
```

All of the commands were successful but when I killed the bat, it didn't drop anything. I tried it with other mobs and they dropped the item. Why does this not work with bats?

Comment: Use this command: 
/summon bat ~ ~2 ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:feather",Count:1b,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Bat Fang"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:1},{id:33,lvl:5}]}},{}],HandDropChances:[2.0F,0.085F]}

It should summon you a bat that has 100 percent drop chance.

Comment: 200% lol. also theres a minimum length

Answer (score 2):

Check the bat's drop-rate on those slots. I believe by default they are all 0 because they never have those slots equipped.

Answer (score 0):

It works you just have to summon the bat with the "Bat Fang".

Here's the command:

```
/summon bat ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:feather",Count:1b,tag:{HideFlags:5,Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Bat Fang"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}},{}],HandDropChances:[2.0F,0.085F]}
```